# How to make VS code's jupyter notebook's codetext bold?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to make code text on jupyter notebook on VS code be bold, but no matter how I tweak the settings.json file I can't seem to find a way to make it happen. As I have noticed, usual python code text in .py files is changing when i change settings.json file but .ipynb file is not reacting. For some reason if I use command palette to change themes jupyter notebook's code is changing color as well but the codetext itself is not becomming bold. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a developer on the VSCode python extension. Currently our notebook editor is implemented as a webview (basically a way for extensions to put a webpage into VS Code's UI). We've tried to match things up as best as we can, but in this scenario we can't support many VS Code editor settings and features. This setting that you are changing is one of the ones that we don't support.

On the plus side, VS Code core team is currently in the process of adding build in notebook support. When we move over to this the notebook cells will be full real VS Code editor instances and will support this setting. This feature is currently in early preview (expect plenty of change and issues) if you right click on a ipynb file in VS Code Insiders and pick "open in preview Notebook Editor."

Answer (score 1):

At present, the [Jupyter notebook](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support) function in VSCode is provided by the python extension.

When it is used as markdown, the text output is bold. (use "`# %%[markdown]`").

[image]

But it does not currently support setting its code bold style. We look forward to its further improvement of this setting.

Comment: Well that's sad, everywhere I code I use bold style, it just looks far more pleasant for my eyes. I tried using pycharm's jupyter support, but it was very bad, and it crashes from time to time.

Comment: @artas2357 Yeah, I see what you mean. You could try other workarounds for better viewing, such as changing the font size. ("setting", "user", "Font", "Font Size").

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of 2024, Visual Studio Code (VS Code) doesn't provide native support for formatting text, including making code text bold, in Jupyter Notebooks. While there are options for bolding text in Markdown cells, the current functionality doesn't support applying formatting styles like bold directly to code blocks.

However, you can achieve a similar effect by using Markdown syntax within Jupyter cells. Markdown allows you to format text, including making it bold. Here's an example:  ** your text **